# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_images'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I want to resize images from 28*28 to 32*32,used `tf.image.resize_images(x_train, (32, 32))`.It returns **AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_images'**.The version of tersorflow is 2.0.0. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16):

It should be `tf.image.resize` See the updated doc https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize

Answer (score 4):

1. The problem
   The tf.image.resize_image function has not been support longer and when you execute the code like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img_final = tf.image.resize_images(img_tensor, [192, 192])
```

You get the following exception:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_images'`

2. The solution
   The function has been renamed into resize. You should change your code like it was done below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow as tf

img_final = tf.image.resize(img_tensor, [192, 192])
```

For more info please check here:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/better-coding.com/solved-tensorflow-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-_api-v2-image-has-no-attribute-resize_images/amp/

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.image.resize(trainX, size=(32,32))
```

More info on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize

Note that trainX should be a 4D or 3D tensor

Answer (score 1):

The function has been renamed to resize. You should change your code like it was done below. It worked for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf

img_final = tf.image.resize(img_tensor, [192, 192])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to TensorFlow Core v2.7.0 docs you should use `tf.compat.v1.image.resize_bilinear` instead of `tf.image.resize_bilinear`

https://github.com/JiahuiYu/neuralgym/issues/16

Comment: This is a better solution than the top voted one

Answer (score 0):

The function has been renamed into resize.
The code can be changed as follows;

import tensorflow as tf

img_A=tf.image.resize(................)